# How would I place an the number of asterixes before the row of asterixes

Tags: python

Given my code i was wondering how would i add the actual number of asterixes before my rows of asterixes.

```
for i in range (1, 10):
    for i in range(0, i):
      print("*", end=' ')
    print("\r")
```

Wanted output:

```
1*
2**
3***
4****
...
```

Current output

```
*
**
***
****
...
```

Comment: where is `print(i)` ?

Comment: `for i in range (1, 10): print(str(i) + "*" * i)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `enumerate` function and thats works because the `range` function is a generator that return a `tuple`

```
for j,i in enumerate(range(1, 10)):
    print("{}{}".format(j+1, "*"*i))
```

edit:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    print("{}{}".format(i, "*"*i))
# this is without the enumerate function
```

Comment: is there a possible way to have the same output without the enumerate function as we are not allowed to use it? thanks for the help too